# The last mapped page

Tags: mmap, memory-mapped-files

POSIX says *"The system always zero-fills any partial page at the end of an object. Further, the system never writes out any modified portions of the last page of an object that are beyond its end."*, and both the Linux and FreeBSD documentations have similar wordings in their man pages.
This suggests that although it is not strictly legitimate to read the last trailing bytes (as they are outside the mapped range), it is still well-defined and designed in a way so it *may* happen without crashing. Even writing to that area is kind of well-defined.

The Windows documentation on the other hand does not say anything about trailing bytes in a less-than-blocksize range, and indeed warns that creating a mapping larger than the file will increase the file size and *will not necessarily* zero the data.
I'm inclined to believe that this is either wrong information or historic (maybe dating back to Win95?). `SetFileValidData` requires non-standard user rights because of the security concern that this might make data from a previously deleted file visible. If the Windows kernel developers allowed anyone to trivially bypass this by mapping any random file, they would have to be quite stupid.
My observation on Windows XP is that any new pages are apparently drawn from the zero pool, and for empty page writeback, either the file is silently made sparse, or the writeback is done in a very, very intelligent way (no noticeable delay at any time, even in the gigabyte range).

**So what is the question about?**

I need to calculate the hash values of (possibly thousands of) files to detect a subset of files that was modified. One can assume SHA-256 as the algorithm, though the actual algorithm does not really matter.
Which as such is of course no big challenge, but like every software, it should run in no time and use no memory, and so on. The usual *realistic* expectations, you get it :-)

The normal way to calculate such a hash is to check whether the message has a size in accordance with the hash function's block size (say e.g. 64 bytes) and zero-fill the last incomplete block if that is not the case. Additionally, the hash may have alignment requirements.
This normally means that you must either make a full copy of the message, or write some special code that hashes all but one block plus a zero-padded copy of the last block. Or something similar. The hash algorithm often silently does that kind of thing on its own behalf, too. In any case it involves moving around a lot of data and more complexity than one would hope for.

Now there is the temptation of directly hashing off a memory-mapped file and relying on the fact that file mapping necessarily depends on memory pages. Thus, both the start address and the physically mapped length are more or less guaranteed to be multiples of 4kB (64kB on some systems). Which of course means they are automatically also multiples of 64, 128, or any other block size that a hash might have.
And for security reasons, actually no OS can afford to give you a page containing stale data.

Which means you could just naively hash over the entire file without worrying about alignments, padding or anything, and avoiding to copy data. It *might* read a few bytes past the end of the mapped range, but it will necessarily still be within the same page.

I am of course aware that this is *technically* illegal. Reading the last bytes outside the mapped range is somewhat comparable to saying that `malloc(5)` always returns an 8-byte block anyway, so it's safe to use the extra 3 bytes.

Though, apart from that obvious thing, is my assumption that this will "just work" reasonable, or is there some serious problem that I fail to see on any major platform?

I'm not really all too much interested in theoretic or historic operating systems, but I'd like to stay *somewhat* portable. That is, I would like to be sure it works reliably on anything you are likely to encounter on a desktop computer or a "typical hosting server" (so, mostly Windows, Linux, BSD, OSX).
If there exists an operating system from 1985 which marks the last page non-readable and enforces strict byte-ranges inside its fault handler, I'm ok with that. You can't (and shouldn't) make everyone happy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The normal way to calculate such a hash is to check whether the message has a size in accordance with the hash function's block size (say e.g. 64 bytes) and zero-fill the last incomplete block if that is not the case.

Not really. This way you couldn't find out the length of the last block (was the zero there or does it come from the padding). Padding works a bit differently: In one schema you always append a single `1` and then `0`s until the end of the block.

In case you data end on a block boundary, it means that another block is needed. This extra block may fall in an extra page. So I don't think it could work the way you described.

> It might read a few bytes past the end of the mapped range, but it will necessarily still be within the same page.

I think this should work on Intel/AMD as there's nothing anybody could do against it. The i386+ CPUs have segments and pages. Segments can end on any byte boundary, but AFAIK no current OS uses them. So as long as you stay in your page, it's all yours.

So I think it could work like this:

- in case the very last block hasn't the full size, do the padding in place
- otherwise, run the last round on a prepared constant block like `1000000000000000`

Comment: Adding a single 1 followed by zero padding has no advantage over padding with zeroes. This is incidentially the convention of one particular hash, but that's it. It does not allow you to determine the length either, unless 1 is an illegal character. Length must be stored separately in any case. The assumption that what's in my page is all mine is probable (as stated in the Q) but _not necessarily_ true. This is what the actual question is about. That said, I can in the mean time confirm that it works reliably under at least 3 versions of Windows (and is guaranteed by POSIX anyway).

Comment: It doesn't help to determine the length, but you don't need to "determine" it. You need to prevent attacks and for this the padding may or may not be sufficient, depending on the hash (e.g. for CubeHash it is). But my point was that you need more space than just the hole at the end of the block.

Comment: I repeat that unless the OS uses segment registers, it has no change to interfere before you cross a page boundary. AFAIK, no modern OS uses segment registers, but that's something you can easily check.

Comment: The assumptions you make are wrong, sorry. Preventing "attacks" is not a priority, detecting file modifications is. However, if anything, then saving explicit length hardens a hash against collision attacks, but even so it's not of interest (still, I need to know the length). Appending any amount of known plaintext adds nothing to avert "attacks". The reason for padding with a known value (including all zeroes) is that hashing the same not-multiple-of-block-sized message gives always the same hash value.

Comment: About an OS not being able to interfere, this could for example be done (in theory, as pointed out in the question) by marking the last page readonly and doing this in the fault handler, much like every modern OS commits thread stacks. It's rather unlikely because it burns CPU for not much gained, insofar I can figure for x86. What I was interested in back then was whether there are any "real" architectures which run in paranoia mode where this is maybe not the case ("real" architectures as in not using punch cards and 7 bit bytes).